# Property Changed from ObservableCollectio<T> to Main class

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I think this is a stupid problem but...

I have a Window class with a `Treeview` bind to a `Observablecollection<T> foo;` T is my class (in another file .cs). 
My `Observablecollection foo` have `OnPropertyChanged` for add/delete element and works ok. 
The problem is for my class T: it has 5 properties and one have `OnPropertyChanged`: when I programmatically change an element of my class T I have `OnPropertyChanged` in `class T` (obviously) but... how can I know it from `Window` class for do something?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to react to property changes in all your classes in your Window class?

Comment: @EmperorAiman I need to do this because when change the property in `class T` I need to add element to another List...

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to listen to propertychange events on the items inside the observable collection?

To do this, I created an extension to ObsercableCollection that bubbles up these events to a collection level, so I can subscribe to collection.CollectionChanged (adding and removing items) and collection.ItemInCollectionChange (property of an item inside the collection has changed):

```
//public class ItemInCollectionChangeEventArgs
public class ItemInCollectionChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Item { get; internal set; }
    public PropertyChangedEventArgs PropertyChangedEventArgs { get; internal set; }
}

public delegate void ItemInCollectionChangeEventHandler(Object sender, ItemInCollectionChangeEventArgs e);

//TODO Make this throw a separate event for refreshing
public class ItemsChangeObservableCollection<T> :
       ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event ItemInCollectionChangeEventHandler ItemInCollectionChangeEvent;

    public ItemsChangeObservableCollection() : base()
    {
    }

    public ItemsChangeObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base()
    {
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemInCollectionChange(ItemInCollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemInCollectionChangeEventHandler handler = ItemInCollectionChangeEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
        }

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        UnRegisterPropertyChanged(this);
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    private void RegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
    {
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UnRegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
    {
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnItemInCollectionChange(new ItemInCollectionChangeEventArgs { Item = sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs = e });
        //base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, @Joe I want to be able to listen to propertychange events on the items inside the observable collection! Nice extension: now I try it!

Comment: Sorry @Joe, what is it `KPIRealTimeViewModel`?

Comment: That's a viewModel I'm using in my project. It shouldn't be there, and, looking at the code, I think it was automatically added when I let VS create the constructor: public ItemsChangeObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) as it automatically creates fields of constructor arguments sometimes (the generated constructor was then edited to make it more general), just delete it (I'll remove it from the answer).